# ORA-1461 with Managed ODP.Net

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

We recently upgraded our solution to the new Managed ODP.Net (v4.121.2.0, from v4.121.1.0) and have come across a problem with udpating to CLOB fields when the field has between 1001 and 4000 characters. When you attempt to do that an error ORA-1461 is thrown from ODP.Net.

Run the same code and data, using the earlier version of ODP.Net and it works fine.  Also, you can insert records with 1001 and 4000 characters, you just can't update them.

I've created a sample program in C# that demonstrates the problem.  The program does the following:

- It creates a 3 column table, one column a CLOB, in the database
- It creates an in-memory .Net DataSet object to match.
- Creates a new record in the DataSet with 1400 characters in the CLOB field.
- Saves the DataSet to the database with an INSERT statement.
- Updates the CLOB field in the DataSet with some new data, again 1400 characters worth of data.
- Saves the DataSet to the database, and the ORA-1461 is thrown.

I don't have an Oracle Support account, so where do you report to Oracle problems with ODP.Net?

Sample C# code that demonstrates the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

class CLOBTest
{
    string _TableName = "CLOBTEST";
    string _ServerName = "servername";
    string _UserName = "username";
    string _Password = "password";

    public void CLOBTest1()
    {
        // Create a physical data table, if needed, in the Oracle DB that has the CLOB column
        CreateTable();

        // Create a dataset for the CLOBTEST table, fill it with a new row
        DataSet CLOBInfo = BuildCLOBTestDataSet();
        DataTable CLOBTable = CLOBInfo.Tables[_TableName];
        DataRow CLOBRow = CLOBTable.NewRow();
        CLOBRow["ACTION_CODE"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("s");
        CLOBRow["DESCRIPTION"] = "CLOB Slim Test";

        // The size of text in the CLOB field is critical to reproducing this defect.
        // It *only* happens when the field has between 1001 and 4000 characters.
        int LOBFieldSize = 1400;
        string CLOBText = DateTime.Now.ToString("s") + " " + new string('-', LOBFieldSize);
        CLOBRow["SCRIPT_TEXT"] = CLOBText.Substring(0, LOBFieldSize);
        CLOBTable.Rows.Add(CLOBRow);

        // Add that row to the DB, and then mark the DS with AcceptChanges
        InsertRow(CLOBInfo);

        // Update that row with some new data.
        CLOBText = DateTime.Now.ToString("s") + " :: " + CLOBText;
        CLOBRow["SCRIPT_TEXT"] = CLOBText.Substring(0, LOBFieldSize);

        // Error (ORA-1461) happens in the UPDATE when the CLOB has 1001 - 4000 characters in it.
        UpdateRow(CLOBInfo);
    }

    private void CreateTable()
    {
        if (TableExists())
            return;

        using (OracleConnection oc = OpenConnection())
        {
            using (OracleCommand ocmd = oc.CreateCommand())
            {
                string SQL = "CREATE TABLE " + _TableName + " (ACTION_CODE VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, SCRIPT_TEXT CLOB, CONSTRAINT CLOBTEST_PK PRIMARY KEY (ACTION_CODE))";
                ocmd.CommandText = SQL;
                ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                AddLogMessage("Table created.");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool TableExists()
    {
        using (OracleConnection oc = OpenConnection())
        {
            using (OracleCommand ocmd = oc.CreateCommand())
            {
                string SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + _TableName + "'";
                ocmd.CommandText = SQL;
                object teRaw = ocmd.ExecuteScalar();
                bool te = (bool)(int.Parse(teRaw.ToString()) > 0);
                AddLogMessage("Table exists? " + te.ToString());
                return te;
            }
        }
    }

    private void InsertRow(DataSet CLOBInfo)
    {
        string SQL = "INSERT INTO " + _TableName + " (ACTION_CODE, DESCRIPTION, SCRIPT_TEXT) VALUES (:pACTION_CODE, :pDESCRIPTION, :pSCRIPT_TEXT)";
        using (OracleConnection oc = OpenConnection())
        {
            using (OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter())
            {
                using (OracleCommand ocmd = oc.CreateCommand())
                {
                    CreateDataParameters(ocmd);

                    ocmd.CommandText = SQL;
                    oda.InsertCommand = ocmd;

                    DataRow[] updRows = CLOBInfo.Tables[_TableName].Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.Added);
                    if (updRows.Length > 0)
                    {
                        int rc = oda.Update(updRows);
                        CLOBInfo.AcceptChanges();
                        AddLogMessage("Row inserted into CLOBTEST. rc = " + rc.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                        AddLogMessage("No rows to insert.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateRow(DataSet CLOBInfo)
    {
        string SQL = "UPDATE " + _TableName + " SET ACTION_CODE = :pACTION_CODE, DESCRIPTION = :pDESCRIPTION, SCRIPT_TEXT = :pSCRIPT_TEXT WHERE ACTION_CODE = :pOLDACTION_CODE";
        using (OracleConnection oc = OpenConnection())
        {
            using (OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter())
            {
                using (OracleCommand ocmd = oc.CreateCommand())
                {
                    ocmd.CommandText = SQL;
                    CreateDataParameters(ocmd);

                    OracleParameter kp = new OracleParameter();
                    kp.ParameterName = "pOLDACTION_CODE";
                    kp.SourceColumn = "ACTION_CODE";
                    kp.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
                    ocmd.Parameters.Add(kp);

                    oda.UpdateCommand = ocmd;
                    DataRow[] updRows = CLOBInfo.Tables[_TableName].Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent);
                    if (updRows.Length > 0)
                    {
                        int rc = oda.Update(updRows);
                        CLOBInfo.AcceptChanges();
                        AddLogMessage("CLOBTEST row updated. rc = " + rc.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                        AddLogMessage("No rows to update.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreateDataParameters(OracleCommand ocmd)
    {
        OracleParameter pActionCode = new OracleParameter();
        pActionCode.ParameterName = "pACTION_CODE";
        pActionCode.SourceColumn = "ACTION_CODE";
        ocmd.Parameters.Add(pActionCode);

        OracleParameter pDescription = new OracleParameter();
        pDescription.ParameterName = "pDESCRIPTION";
        pDescription.SourceColumn = "DESCRIPTION";
        ocmd.Parameters.Add(pDescription);

        OracleParameter pScriptText = new OracleParameter();
        pScriptText.ParameterName = "pSCRIPT_TEXT";
        pScriptText.SourceColumn = "SCRIPT_TEXT";
        ocmd.Parameters.Add(pScriptText);
    }

    private DataSet BuildCLOBTestDataSet()
    {
        DataSet ads = new DataSet();
        DataTable at = new DataTable("CLOBTEST");
        DataColumn ac = at.Columns.Add("ACTION_CODE", typeof(string));
        at.Columns.Add("DESCRIPTION", typeof(string));
        at.Columns.Add("SCRIPT_TEXT", typeof(string));
        at.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { ac };
        ads.Tables.Add(at);
        return ads;
    }

    private OracleConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        OracleConnection oc = null;
        try
        {
            OracleClientFactory ocf = new OracleClientFactory();
            DbConnectionStringBuilder csb = ocf.CreateConnectionStringBuilder();
            csb["Data Source"] = _ServerName;
            csb["User ID"] = _UserName;
            csb["Password"] = _Password;
            string cs = csb.ConnectionString;
            oc = new OracleConnection(cs);
            oc.Open();
            AddLogMessage("Connection opened.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AddLogMessage("Error Opening Connection! " + ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
        return oc;
    }

    private void AddLogMessage(string msg)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:T} - {1}", DateTime.Now, msg));
    }
}
```

Comment: Found some postings on Oracle website that seem to be related:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3649551
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3640248

Comment: Looks like you went to the right place. If you don't have a support account, OTN ODP.NET forum is the best place to report bugs. The problem though is that the fix is generally only available in a timely fashion for people who have a support account. So you may need to work around this by binding as a CLOB like they recommend in that thread you found. FYI, if your employer (or the person you are contracting for) has support for the Oracle Database, they automatically have support for ODP.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two workarounds are shown in this thread: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3649551

### Workaround one:

Configure your CLOB parameters as `OracleDbType.Clob` **and** `ParameterDirection.InputOutput`.

### Workaround two:

Configure your CLOB parameters as `OracleDbType.Clob` and explicitly set the value to a `OracleClob` object.

### Fix:

The bug is now known to Oracle, so hopefully a fixed version will be released soon.

**Edit:** [Patch 20361140](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchDetail?patchId=20361140&languageId=0&platformId=233&requestId=18735492) should fix it.